# What is the best way to create a dynamic data structure off use input?

Tags: mysql, dynamic-tables

I wrote some code that creates database tables based on user input. From what I can tell, this seems to be bad form. I'm also not sure if user input is sanitized sufficiently to prevent SQL injection. This is the code I have in Javascript:

```
  function tableName(dialog_id){
    return settings.table_prefix+parseInt(dialog_id);
  }   
  
  function generateTableSQL(dialog_id, fields){
    function generateColumnSQL(field){
      // take first word then strip non alphanumeric or underscore from field name
      let name = field.name.replace(/ .*/,'').replace(/\W/g, '');
      let type = COLUMN_TYPES[field.type];
      if(! (name && type)){
        return null;
      }else if(name[0].match(/[0-9]/)){
        return null;
      }
      return "`"+name+"` "+type;
    }
    let columns = _.map(fields, generateColumnSQL);
    let isInvalid = _.find(columns, (c) => {c==null});
    if(isInvalid){
      return null;
    }
    return [
      "CREATE TABLE `"+tableName(dialog_id)+"` (\n",
      "`id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, \n",
      columns.join(", \n"), 
      ") ENGINE="+DB_ENGINE+" DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;"
    ].join("\n");
  }
```

I want to know what the best way to store data with a structure that's generated by a user. I could do something like create a single table then call SQL code to insert a row for each column of data. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO saved_data (table_name, field, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

But then each field would have to be stored as the same datatype. What's the best way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I would never let user input be used as literal SQL syntax (or any other language, e.g. `eval`), no matter how much you try to sanitize it. Inevitably, users will find a way to blow up your server somehow. For example, creating a table with 10,000 columns. Or even a table with 200 columns of type BLOB. Or numerous other ways they can define tables that will cause errors or runaway resource use.

Comment: The better way is to allow them to submit a _request_ to create a table, then you or another qualified database developer can review the request and make sure it's legitimate. I understand you want to let users define their own tables, but they are not to be trusted with that power.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the users creating tables will be website administrators. And yes, the ability to request 10k columns was an oversight. Thanks for pointing that out. Data types shouldn't be an issue because they are pulled via codes from a lookup map. The config is setup so that generated tables can set in a separate database from the website with separate MySQL credentials so any damage caused by user input can at least be somewhat contained. If there is a better solution, I'd still like to know.

Comment: So you are basically reinventing [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)? It's a browser tool for website administrators to use to create tables and prototype SQL queries.

Comment: Not quite. A backend user creates dialog tree/graphs, which are presented to front-end users. When configuring a graph, administrators have the option to save any number of variables set when users traverse the graph. So, when data is being captured each graph will have a corresponding table for storing user input data.

Comment: Okay, I see. So the fields correspond to the variables, which are defined by the graph configuration. That sounds like there are some sensible controls on what types of graphs can be created, and the fields are more or less under your control. Also the users in this case are more or less trustworthy, so we can assume they aren't trying maliciously to subvert your controls or cause mischief. In that case, I would consider your function safe enough.

Comment: Not related to your question — I would recommend using utf8mb4 instead of utf8. The traditional utf8 (aka utf8mb3) is practically deprecated, and utf8mb4 is a superset.